# R : How to iterate sum across multiple columns?

Tags: r, loops, sum, iteration

I am trying to iterate/loop a sum across multiple non-consecutive columns. My objective is to compute the subscale score of multiple questionnaires measured repeatedly across time.

Dataset for one questionnaire of *x* items and **n** time-points:

```
df <- tibble(
  ID = 1:5,
  itemA_1 = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemB_1 = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemC_1 = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemD_1 = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemx_1 = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemA_3 = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemB_3 = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemC_3 = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemD_3 = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemx_3 = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemA_n = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemB_n = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemC_n = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemD_n = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
  itemx_n = sample(100, 5, TRUE),
)
```

The sum for one specific time point works just fine:

```
df %>% mutate(total_1 = sum(c(itemA_1, itemC_1, itemD_1))
```

This loop does not work:

```
for (i in c(1, 3, n)) {
    df %>% mutate(total_i = sum(c(itemA_i, itemC_i, itemD_i))
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and do a group by `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df %>%
   pivot_longer(cols =-ID, names_to = c("item", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
  filter(item %in% c("itemA", "itemC", "itemD")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE,
       .names = "total_{.col}")) %>%
  left_join(df, .)
```

-output

```
> df1
# A tibble: 5 × 19
     ID itemA_1 itemB_1 itemC_1 itemD_1 itemx_1 itemA_3 itemB_3 itemC_3 itemD_3 itemx_3 itemA_n itemB_n itemC_n itemD_n itemx_n total_1
  <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1     1      69      27      56      44      54      53      66      28      67      19      65      38      12      45      33     250
2     2      31      65       7      34      84      19      64      70      27      23      98      65      94      71     100     221
3     3      58      34      68      18      69     100      24      47      54      60      47      48      81      61      22     247
4     4      95      16      85      34       9      28      73      57      79      60      57      31      16      24      84     239
5     5      19      66      43      25      35      31      39      17      15      84      10      23     100       6      74     188
# … with 2 more variables: total_3 <int>, total_n <int>
```

---

If we want to use the `for` loop, then `paste` the column names with `i`, evaluate (`!!`) while assigning (`:=`)

```
library(stringr)
for (i in c(1, 3, 'n')) {
     df <- df %>% 
   mutate(!! str_c("total_", i) :=   
      rowSums(across(all_of(str_c(c("itemA_", "itemC_", "itemD_"), i)))))
     }
```

But, note that this will not be dynamic as we have to manually include the `1, 2, ..., n` in the loop

-checking the output from `for` loop and reshaping

```
> all.equal(df1$total_1, df$total_1)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(df1$total_3, df$total_3)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(df1$total_n, df$total_n)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun, the loop works great, although the first suggestion compute the total sum at each time-points but not the sum of the specific items.

Comment: @OlivierPDS sorry, when I posted the solution, I was thinking that it should be dynamic. i.e. it should include the `itemB` as well.  Now, I understand you wanted to remove those items?

Comment: @OlivierPDS You need a `filter` step after the `pivot_longer`, (updated)

Comment: @OlivierPDS I didn't catch that either. I've updated my answer to filter the specific desired values too.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base R option without pivoting, where we first select the columns that we want to sum, then get the unique suffix names, then we can use `rowSums` to get the sum of each group (i.e., each unique suffix). Then, I update the column names, and then `merge` with the original dataframe.

```
df_sum <- df[, grepl( "ID|itemA|itemC|itemD", names(df))]

suffixes <- unique(sub("^[^_]*_", "", colnames(df_sum)))

df2 <- sapply(suffixes, function(x) rowSums(df_sum[,endsWith(colnames(df_sum), x)]))
colnames(df2)[-1] <- paste("total", colnames(df2)[-1], sep = "_")
merge(x = df, y = df2, by = "ID", all.x = TRUE)
```

**Output**

```
  ID itemA_1 itemB_1 itemC_1 itemD_1 itemx_1 itemA_3 itemB_3 itemC_3 itemD_3 itemx_3 itemA_n itemB_n itemC_n itemD_n itemx_n total_1 total_3 total_n
1  1      92      84      31      74      77      26      71      92      59      70      47      54       7       6      95     197     177      60
2  2      49       6      40       6      94      61      69      58      49      62      66      13      94      52      23      95     168     212
3  3      67      69      34      56      44      94      69       1      52      96      62      64      34      78      67     157     147     174
4  4      86      33      85      87      30      33      26      15      70      97      34      36      74      58      87     258     118     166
5  5      49      25      23      56      63       4      84      35      92      34      33      62      95      77      50     128     131     205
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, itemA_1 = c(92L, 49L, 67L, 86L, 49L), 
    itemB_1 = c(84L, 6L, 69L, 33L, 25L), itemC_1 = c(31L, 40L, 
    34L, 85L, 23L), itemD_1 = c(74L, 6L, 56L, 87L, 56L), itemx_1 = c(77L, 
    94L, 44L, 30L, 63L), itemA_3 = c(26L, 61L, 94L, 33L, 4L), 
    itemB_3 = c(71L, 69L, 69L, 26L, 84L), itemC_3 = c(92L, 58L, 
    1L, 15L, 35L), itemD_3 = c(59L, 49L, 52L, 70L, 92L), itemx_3 = c(70L, 
    62L, 96L, 97L, 34L), itemA_n = c(47L, 66L, 62L, 34L, 33L), 
    itemB_n = c(54L, 13L, 64L, 36L, 62L), itemC_n = c(7L, 94L, 
    34L, 74L, 95L), itemD_n = c(6L, 52L, 78L, 58L, 77L), itemx_n = c(95L, 
    23L, 67L, 87L, 50L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

**Benchmark**

```
df1 <- df
df2 <- df

bm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(akrun_tidyverse = {df %>%
                                       pivot_longer(cols =-ID, names_to = c("item", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
                                       filter(item %in% c("itemA", "itemC", "itemD")) %>%
                                       group_by(ID) %>%
                                       summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE,
                                                        .names = "total_{.col}")) %>%
                                       left_join(df, .)},
                                     akrun_loop = {for (i in c(1, 3, 'n')) {
                                       df1 <- df1 %>% 
                                         mutate(!! str_c("total_", i) :=   
                                                  rowSums(across(all_of(str_c(c("itemA_", "itemC_", "itemD_"), i)))))
                                     }},
                                     andrew_baseR = {df_sum <- df2[, grepl( "ID|itemA|itemC|itemD", names(df2))];
                                     suffixes <- unique(sub("^[^_]*_", "", colnames(df_sum)));
                                     df3 <- sapply(suffixes, function(x) rowSums(df_sum[,endsWith(colnames(df_sum), x)]));
                                     colnames(df3)[-1] <- paste("total", colnames(df3)[-1], sep = "_");
                                     merge(x = df, y = df3, by = "ID", all.x = TRUE)}, 
                                     times = 1000)

autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::map_dfc`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map_dfc(c("1","3","n"),~ data.frame(apply(select(df, ends_with(.x)), 1, sum)) %>% 
    set_names(str_c("Total_",.x))) %>% bind_cols(df, .)

#>   ID itemA_1 itemB_1 itemC_1 itemD_1 itemx_1 itemA_3 itemB_3 itemC_3 itemD_3
#> 1  1      89      33      84      15      86       8       9      18      98
#> 2  2      37       2      32      52      37      79      37      31      57
#> 3  3       5      21      54      58      25      74      43       7      14
#> 4  4      19      76      71      84      75      34      72     100      33
#> 5  5      78      52      58      42       5      28      90      21      95
#>   itemx_3 itemA_n itemB_n itemC_n itemD_n itemx_n Total_1 Total_3 Total_n
#> 1      78       5      52       4      73      88     307     211     222
#> 2      82      88      78       3       3      69     160     286     241
#> 3      41      60      73      59      32      87     163     179     311
#> 4      97      86      33      81      44      22     325     336     266
#> 5      37       4       9      35       5      38     235     271      91
```